# Specifying a minimum difference in values from one time point to another

Tags: matrix, difference, minimum, timedelta

Bit stuck with a problem, and hoping somebody can help if this is ok? I have a data matrix of samples in columns and genes in rows. the columsn represent time points.. so time point 1, 2, 3 and 4. I have counts for each gene to represent their expression.

But what I would like to do is the following:

Filter genes that have a specific change across the time points.

So for example, I would like to be able to look at genes that change from one time point to another **only** if it has a difference of a minimum change of 50 counts or more.  So if the change from one gene to another were 45 counts (for example), it would be rejected. Is there any way of doing this and if so, would somebody be kind enough to share some code for this?

Please see code attached of an example matrix. Essentially, I would like to specify that the the average change between the first 5 columns (which are 5 replicates)  can only be included if the change for each gene (ENSMU etc) changes by a minimum value of 50 from one replicate to another... I hope this makes sense and I would be happy to ellaborate...

```
**X51378P3 X51378P4 X48275P5 X48277P1 X48277P2** X28046 X23154 X23156 
X23157 X23241 **X8657 X10459  X8302 X8726 X8727** X8309 X5260 X47471 
X51394   X18
ENSMUSG00000042096        0        2        0        1        3      
2     13      5      3      6   238    211    149   182   214   843   
831   1072    815   971
ENSMUSG00000033208       91       47      100       41       79    
764    848    744    491    671  2361   2888   2323  2297  2778  4613  
6634   6603   5477  4924
ENSMUSG00000021750       46       51       28       28       34     
89     90     81     88     73  9083   6238   3876  6754  7066 11727 
10135  16857  10669 12581
ENSMUSG00000041205      290      141      156      122      146    
431    432    377    310    388  1514   1714   1363  1428  1677  1492  
2036   1465   1573  1585
ENSMUSG00000026556     4260     3486     3545     2315     3090   
2818   2039   2204   2139   2241   807    973    689   787  1094   
466   660    460    457   579
ENSMUSG00000032908      112       77       78       76       98    
399    286    359    218    282  1451   1266    897  1183  1416  1881  
2243   2281   1862  2144
ENSMUSG00000045246        7        4       11        7       11     
13     29     36     19     14   762    958    810   905   720  2950  
2390   2916   2684  2878
ENSMUSG00000023019      159      108      104       96      116     
68     94     94     62    132   878   1039    774   941   829  3164  
3191   3405   2671  3019
ENSMUSG00000029054        9        1       13        2        4     
27     39     49     13     35  1834   2277   1054  1744  2449  3905  
4228   3240   2941  3489
ENSMUSG00000010476     9380     8541     8906     5609     7406   
4478   4422   4865   3739   4003   886   1473    979   956  1199   
247   380    434    297   375
ENSMUSG00000020788       79      109       93       53       91    
124    163    212    128    135  3561   3396   1944  3128  3754  6632  
6844   5198   5595  6646
ENSMUSG00000047945    18196    14417    16349    10746    14262  
19114  13732  13902  12339  13406  4224   7321   4514  5056  6271   
702   899    630    883   741
ENSMUSG00000022096      183      120      156       76      159    
384    205    160    225    189  2466   2488   1958  2504  2921  2955  
3255   3218   2442  2928
ENSMUSG00000020734      233       85      157      150      108    
183    204    253    187    182  5854   4614   2719  4949  6563 12011 
14573  10291   9136 12527
```

So for example, if you look at ENSMUSG00000029054, the average value of the first 5 columns is 5.8 and the average of the second 5 (which would represent another sample) is 32.6.  So the difference between the 2 is 26.8. So what I would like to do is filter this matrix such that the average change between each sample is a minimum of 50..

I hope this is clear and I would be happy to provide any more information if required.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a read through [mcve]. Being more specific and sharing your existing code will more likely encourage useful responses.

Comment: Many thanks!! have edited original post :) hope this is better!